# How to get link title information with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have such table (below). I want to get someone's detail information if someones carry mouse cursor over this name. For example, if someone takes cursor over name "John" this information : "Location: USA, Sex:Male, City:Los angeles" will be shown to him. How can I do that with jQuery?

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="1" width="100%" class="tariff_table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="150" valign="top" class="title_td">
<strong>Name</strong></td>
<td valign="top" class="title_td">

<strong>Surname</strong><strong></strong>
<p></p></td>
<td valign="top" class="title_td">

<strong>Middle Name </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">

John</td>
<td valign="top">

Locaste</td>
<td valign="top">

Sawqa</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">

Jafde</td>
<td valign="top">Saqzw</td>
<td valign="top">

Porda</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Where will the other data information come from?

Comment: @voigtan I did not understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs some tweaking, but it is basically what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/8yQGW/2/

You create a fixed element that contains your tooltip. On hover over a row/cell you display it. When you mouseout - hide it. Pretty straightforward.

Right now it is a little buggy because if you mouseover the tooltip it causes the hide code to fire. You might want to switch it to mousemove from hover and have the tooltip follow the cursor. You didn't specify so I am not going to try guessing your intent.

```
$('td').hover( 
    function(e) { 
        console.log(e.clientX + ' : ' + e.clientY );
        $('.tooltip').html($(this).html()).css( { top: e.clientY + 15, left: e.clientX + 15 } ).fadeIn('fast'); ; 
    },     
    function(e) { $('.tooltip').fadeOut('fast'); } 
);
```

Comment: Now It worked. But I want different information (not one) for different text.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for this. See the [demo](http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb.tooltip/tooltip.html)

http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/2009/02/07/mbtooltip/

Comment: exactly like that. But there many lines in javascript file. I want short code.